# How to connect a Stellaris account with Steam?

Tags: steam, achievements, stellaris

This is how I connect my Stellaris account connected with Steam:

[image]

And I log in with this Stellaris account while playing game:

[image]

However, I suspect it's isn't correctly, because:

- I've played Stellaris for 13 hours and should have unlocked many achievements, but [none of the achievements are unlocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gUGv.png).
- I've purchased [Stellaris: Nova Edition Upgrade Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/616190/), but the "spider race" never occurred in my game.

What an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get achievements in Stellaris you actually need to go one step further than with other Paradox titles.

First off, you don't need to connect your Steam-Account to your Paradox-Account as there isn't a feature to sync achievements anyway.

The things needed to get Achievements:

1. Unmodified Checksum (yours is correct in the Screenshot)
2. You need to play in Ironman Mode
3. You need to have enabled Cloud-Sync in Steam (at least I had to a couple of versions ago, no idea if this still applies)

However, there are a [couple](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/opt-in-1-5-1-patch.1010284/#post-22635476) of known bugs which prevent you from getting Achievements (because Paradox mess everything up). In that case you could consider using the [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam/) for giving yourself the achievements you deserve.

As a sidenote to the SAM, I know it is controversial, but I really don't see a problem with using it to acquire achievements you were bugged out of (in first line in games like Stellaris where such Achievements can take days or even weeks to acquire).