# What makes a game ineligible for achievements?

Tags: xbox-one, stellaris

I have played 3 full (disastrous) games of *Stellaris* so far but all of them were using a custom race and galaxy generation stats. Now I want to play for achievements, and every time I go to start a new game it shows the following red text at the bottom of the screen:

[image: settings]

It shows this text even when I'm using a default empire, or a randomized empire, and I've reset all the settings to default.

Why am I ineligible for achievements? Can anyone tell from my screenshot if there is a setting that didn't go back to default, even though I pressed that reset button?

---

EDIT: As pointed out in comments below, there is an answer to another question ([How to connect a Stellaris account with Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312605/how-to-connect-a-stellaris-account-with-steam)) that also includes the info in my answer. However, the title describes a different issue (I personally scrolled past it before posting my question), so rather than mark as a duplicate I will leave this up for now in case someone else has the same confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect a Stellaris account with Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312605/how-to-connect-a-stellaris-account-with-steam)

Comment: ^ That one's about Steam but the answer covers all the things required for achievements.

Comment: The questions are nothing alike

Comment: @TylerH (and review/close voters) This question is not a duplicate. While the linked question does mention the solution for this, the two posts ask very different questions

Comment: @Wrigglenite & Wondercricket the questions are quite similar actually, it just might be a little confusing to you because there are two questions being asked in the target and neither of them are actually reflected in the title. One of the questions, the one that the (accepted) answer focuses exclusively on, covers what the requirements are for getting achievements. The answer would serve equally well as the answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have edited for clarity about the other post that includes this information. No sweat if this is closed in the long run though, as long as the solution is out there I'm sure people will find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, after messing around with the settings for a minute I figured out that **turning on Iron Man mode enables achievements**.

Comment: Just to mention it, it seems that you can use **any settings you want** with Iron Man enabled, and you can still get achievements. This makes no sense to me, but I can confirm.

Comment: That's pretty standard for Paradox games. The game only cares that you're not save scumming to get achievements.

Comment: I believe there are also some mods (in the PC version) that will disable achievements, but I'm not sure if that applies to the Xbox version - (I don't know if there's an option to install mods on the Xbox.)

Comment: Ironman is not the 'hardest' mode (as your comment indicates); it just means you can't use console commands (cheats), modify the checksum (modify the save game file), or make multiple saves to "go back" if you mess up. I earned most achievements on the default/easiest difficulty setting in my first Ironman playthrough.

Comment: Yeah it seemed super punishing until I realized you could mod any other setting. Makes sense  just unexpected.